# Trim H264 Video and wrap in MP4 without re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, raspberry-pi3, h.264, mp4box

So I have a Raspberry Pi app that records output from the on-board camera. These files are recorded as H264. After a user presses a button I want to display a portion of that video with OMXPlayer. OMXPlayer always needs an MP4 container ( it always ignores FPS ).

I don't want to wrap the entire H264 into an MP4 as that takes too much time.

My solution would be trim the last 30 seconds and place into MP4 container. Can I do this in one step **without** copying the entire content of the H264 into the MP4 first?

I don't want to re-encode this and I'm looking for the fastest operation possible.

Comment: When you say wrapping full stream "*takes too much time*" - you aren't re-encoding during this step, right?

Comment: No, just to write the file out again takes 2-3 secs for a 30 second file. I'd like to respond to user input as quickly as possible

Comment: Not possible, since raw streams don't have an index.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fast, just do a stream copy of the file to an mp4 container.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUTFILE -sseof 30 -c:v copy -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Comment: Raw H264 files don't have duration metadata so sseof won't work.

Comment: Yes, it seems to ignore -sseof unfortunately, I'm not sure this is possible

Comment: Incidentally its a lot faster than MP4Box and by segmenting the files and concating the required ones, I think I have a solution, so thanks++